# python ssl issue opening certificate files

Tags: python, ssl

Here is my code:

```
import ssl
def main():
    context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
    context.load_cert_chain(certfile=os.path.join('keys', 'server.crt'),
                            keyfile=os.path.join('keys', 'server.key'),
                            password="my certificate password")
    # more code to follow

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I have confirmed that my two files look like:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
 # my key file
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
 # my cert file
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

It was hanging on the context.load_cert_chain(...) line.  No exceptions are thrown and it never returns.  It turns out it was missing the password parameter (for the certificate)

Comment: Maybe it is waiting for you to enter the password of the key? From the documentation: *If the password argument is not specified and a password is required, OpenSSL’s built-in password prompting mechanism will be used to interactively prompt the user for a password.*

Comment: That was it exactly!  thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have edited the code, adding the missing password parameter thanks to Steffen Ullrich